# Is there a cross-platform version of win32 CopyFile?

Tags: c++, cross-platform

If I need to, I suppose I could write my own version using streams, but this seems like a basic piece of functionality which should be out there somewhere.

Comment: Across which platforms, though? What libraries do you use/allow for the scope of the question?

Comment: Are you looking for an equivalent in the C++ std lib? If so, there is no such thing.

Comment: Primarily looking at posix and windows platforms.  Looking at boost/filesystem. It looks promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `boost::filesystem` library contains a `copy_file` function. It is documented 
[at the boost website.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#copy_file)

It can be used like this

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

std::string sourcePath = "./sourceFile.txt";
std::string destPath  = "./destFile.txt";
boost::filesystem::copy_file(sourcePath, destPath, boost::filesystem::copy_option::overwrite_if_exists);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are cross platform libraries with that functionality, such as [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) and [Poco](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.File.html).

Answer (score 0):

2NinerRomeo's post contains an error: it should say overwrite_if_exists whare it says overwrite_if_exitsts